# Install an apk from JAR / find path in String inisde JAR

Tags: java, android, jar, path, apk

I write two titles because it can arrive from both sides.

I want to install an apk that its inside of my java project (this means, install an apk from the java desktop application (jar file)).
I can do this from Eclipse pushing in "run" and it works fine. 
The problem that I have is that when I create the jar file the path of the apk is missing.

This works in Eclipse when I run the code:

```
String apk = "foo.apk"
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime(); 
rt.exec ("cmd /c adb install "+apk );
```

---

I know that I should use something like

```
String apk = "foo.apk"
InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(apk);
```

but then I don't have the path of this for using the

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime(); 
rt.exec ("cmd /c adb install "+apk );
```

I need the the path of the file to send the command to install the apk.

In my project I have the foo.apk file in the code package, in the src folder, in an "asset" folder.
It doesn't matter to me if I have to move it but it has to be inside the jar.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Files in the "assets" folder of your project are packed up in your APK. But when you install your application on the device, they are still inside the APK. They aren't on the filesystem as individual files. What you need to do here is to copy foo.apk from your assets folder inside your application to a temporary file on the Android file system (SD card or private data area). Then you can install it the way you've indicated.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself well.
This code is for a java desktop application. 
I want to install the apk from a java desktop application.
There is no apk packed the foo.apk is packaged in the jar file that is the java desktop application.